# HTTP Communication failure - 500 Native SSL error

Tags: json, xml, https

We are using Google API to compute mileage for our travel. Everything was working fine for over 1 year, however we started having the below said issue in the last couple of months.

Our program is able to connect to the API, the API returning with the error message `http_communication_failure`. The exact error is Application Server

> Error 500 Native SSL error 
>   Error is logged with Tag: {0001fee7}Thu Jun
>   21 09:36:49 2018

When I pasted the URL in the browser, it is returning the mileage information.  However through the API call (receive data) in the program, we are getting this error message.

No program changes or Certificate changes have been done in the last 1 year. Our Basis team looked in to the possible issues with SSL.  Everything seems to be OK from our end.  I looked through your troubleshooting page, and tried all the suggested solutions.  Nothing seem to fix our problem. Please let us know what else we need to look at.

```
 CONCATENATE 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=' lv_dep '&destinations=' lv_arr '&units=imperial'
                '&key=' lv_key
                INTO lv_http_url.

    CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>create_by_url
      EXPORTING
        url                = lv_http_url
        ssl_id             = 'ANONYM'
      IMPORTING
        client             = lo_http_client
      EXCEPTIONS
        argument_not_found = 1
        plugin_not_active  = 2
        internal_error     = 3
        others             = 4.

    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.

      lo_http_client->send( EXCEPTIONS http_communication_failure = 1
                                       http_invalid_state         = 2 ).

      CALL METHOD lo_http_client->receive
        EXCEPTIONS
          http_communication_failure = 1
          http_invalid_state         = 2
          http_processing_failed     = 3
          others                     = 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. See if port 443 is create in Trns: smicm, if you can't see it, create it.
2. increase the trace in menu go to->trace level.
3. call Appi and see log.
4. if you see a error about SSL, export the certificate from your PC, I supose is "google trust service".
5. go trns: STRUST in SAP and inport the new certificate.